# How do I initialize transactional replication from a backup at a URL?

Tags: replication, azure-blob-storage

I created a publication on my server. I had to use this special option so that I could initialize replication from a backup:

```
exec sp_addpublication 
    ...
    @allow_initialize_from_backup = N'true', 
    ...
```

Then, I took a backup of my database:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [MyDatabase] 
    TO URL = 'https://fakestorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/MyDatabase.bak' 
    WITH CREDENTIAL = 'mycredential', COMPRESSION, STATS = 5;
GO
```

And restored from it on the target server:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDatabase] 
  FROM URL = 'https://fakestorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/MyDatabase.bak'
  WITH CREDENTIAL = 'mycredential'
    ,MOVE 'MyDatabase' to 'SomePath\Data\MyDatabase.mdf'
    ,MOVE 'MyDatabase_log' to 'SomePath\Log\MyDatabase.ldf'
    ,STATS = 5 
GO
```

Now I'm ready to create the subscriber. The problem I'm having is that I don't know what options to provide to the [sp_addsubscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addsubscription-transact-sql) procedure.

I can make it through the process using a regular hard drive instead of a URL. I could see data being replicated from source to target. I back up to disk, copy the backup to the target server, restore, and then initialize from backup using this command:

```
exec sp_addsubscription 
    @publication = N'MyPub', 
    @subscriber = N'MyTargetServer', 
    @destination_db = N'MyDatabase', 
    @subscription_type = N'Push', 
    @sync_type = N'initialize with backup', 
    @article = N'all', 
    @update_mode = N'read only', 
    @subscriber_type = 0,
    @backupdevicetype = 'disk',
    @backupdevicename = 'D:\Backups\MyDatabase.bak'
```

How do I tweak these options in order to initialize replication from a URL (which in my case is an Azure blob storage container that both servers have the credentials for)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very good question but at the moment, initializing a subscription from a backup stored in Windows Azure Blob storage is not currently supported. I believe this would be a very cool feature for replication and I'm sure the folks at Microsoft would agree. I suggest proposing this idea on [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server).

However, since you've already restored the backup, and the schema and data are already in place at the subscriber, try executing sp_addsubscription with the **@sync_type** of 'replication support only' and see if that meets your needs.

More details for initializing a subscription manually can be found in [How to: Initialize a Subscription Manually](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147897.aspx).

Comment: I wonder why anyone would initialize with a backup when there is an option to initialize without a backup. Anyway, I took your advice and posted on UserVoice (still pending so you may not be able to see it yet, but [here's the link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/33549475-allow-initializing-replication-from-a-url-backup) anyway).